# GraphQL + Apollo requests

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

If I have an app being built with GraphQL + Apollo + React, just wondering if I have say 3 components on the page which each components makes a different query, does that mean that 3 requests will be made from the client to the server and 3 will be returned? Bit lost how it works as I gather GraphQL condenses API calls down into 1 request, but how does it work in the above scenario in terms of requests from client to server, then server back to client?

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/advanced/network-layer.html#query-deduplication):

> Query deduplication can help reduce the number of queries that are sent over the wire. It is turned on by default, but can be turned off by passing queryDeduplication: false to the context on each requests or using the defaultOptions key on Apollo Client setup. If turned on, query deduplication happens before the query hits the network layer. Query deduplication can be useful if many components display the same data, but you don’t want to fetch that data from the server many times. It works by comparing a query to all queries currently in flight. If an identical query is currently in flight, the new query will be mapped to the same promise and resolved when the currently in-flight query returns.

In other words, as long as you don't explicitly set `queryDeduplication` to `false`, Apollo will skip sending a request if it matches any in-flight requests.

While GraphQL provides the ability to send multiple queries within the same request (and Apollo supports this ability), it's up to you to compose such a query -- GraphQL does **not** do this for you automatically. In order to **batch** multiple queries into a single request using Apollo, you have to use [apollo-link-batch-http](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/batch-http.html).